# Is there a way to backup save files in Torchlight?

Tags: steam, torchlight

I've run into issues with corrupted save files in Torchlight before due to a mixup in installed mods between my two computers. Whoops.

Is there some way to duplicate my save games? I'd like to have a backup, but because the saves are constant across the Steam Cloud, I'm a little confused on if this is even possible, or where to look for the saved games in the first place.

Comment: Have you considered using [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) ([referral link for bonus space](http://db.tt/RUVJwLf)) to keep your mod folders in sync between your computers? That way it won't happen again. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Torchlight saves are kept in `%APPDATA%\runic games\torchlight\save\` on Windows, `~/.runicgames/Torchlight/Save/` on Linux and `~/Library/Application Support/runic games/torchlight/save/` on OS X. You can back up your save files by simply making a copy of this folder somewhere else.

Every time you start or quit Torchlight, the folder is synchronized with the version on Steam's servers. If the Last Modified date of your save files are newer than the version in the cloud, Steam will ask you what to do.

Comment: This is perfect. Now the only reason my characters will get deleted is me!

Comment: Sweet, now I can keep enchanting my items without worrying about breaking them! Ha!